# Do web applications made with Express.js need to be bundled for distribution? And what is the purpose for a distribution version of an app?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, express, webpack

I hope the question is clear enough, I'll to to explain more in depth, but before that, I want to first say I'm new/fresh to web development.

I have been developing some apps on my own and have also followed some udemy courses and what I have had difficulty understanding is what is the purpose for a distribution version of the web app you are developing.

I first started a course that had some intro to PHP, MySQL, Wordpress, with a larger emphasis on HTLM/CSS and Javascript. The last project in this course was a single page website that used Webpack to bundle the project and create a distribution version of the project.

After this I followed a course which main project was a multi page app that used Express.js with .ejs , Node.js, Bootstrap and PostgreSQL, but I did notice there was no bundling for a distribution version of the app.

Last, but not least, I did another course that used React for the client side, and in the end there was a  script for generating a bundle for distribution.

As I started moving my projects to a static server and getting them up and running forever with PM2, I stopped for a bit and was wondering why is there even a need for a distribution version of a project even needed if the websites look the same, but I assume the reason is so it runs more smoothly on a browser.
I'm just making assumptions here, but I assume the javascript from all the dependencies are put together on a single .js file or a small set of files to make it easier on the browser to process the website? Also for version control?

But if creating a distribution version of your app optimizes it for a browser, then how come Express.js doesn't offer this?

Maybe this is a very stupid question, I'm still confused by a lot of this stuff.
Maybe because they can do similar stuff, like webpack can throw up a server so you can see your app running, like React, but to access a database, you need to make an api call to a backend program like Express.js through axios or fetch. But Express.js is a server that can make query calls to a database and lets you see your app through views/.ejs.

Again, sorry if this sounds all really dumb, I just don't know anyone who I can ask these questions.

Comment: `But if creating a distribution version of your app optimizes it for a browser, then how come Express.js doesn't offer this?` Because express doesn't run in the browser.

Comment: expressjs runs on your server and these dependancies are defined in your `packages.json`. You run `npm install` before running your project so they don't get packaged and compiled.

Comment: When I code for running simple html files with JS script files then I don't need webpack. I had a similar question before when I made a chrome extension which only uses `.html` and `.js` format. But I wanted to import ReactJS on my extension as React needs some npm modules to run. I got an answer while googling and understood why webpack is needed.

Comment: A chrome extension only can accept `.html` and `.js`. But as webpack [website](https://webpack.js.org/) explain on  the web, it makes various modules and js files on React into a single js file to make `.html` file available to import the js file. So many modules and jsx files on ReactJS can't be uploaded on `.html` format except bundling by webpack. After bundled, ReactJS app gets into single one javascript file.

Comment: @tkausl thank you very much for that answer, it makes it clearer.

Comment: @ptree thank you, so in a way, the server, takes more of the load than the browser, if I'm understanding it correctly?

Comment: Server side codes handle server side loads. They have different duties and most of the time they can replace each other. Think front-end and backend separately.